# Eror on syntax can someone check

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BOBOT = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_BOBOT + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_HP_ID +" INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_BATERAI + "TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_KAMERA +" TEXT NOT NULL,"+ KEY_RAM +"TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_INTERNAL +" TEXT NOT NULL," + ")";

it says Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE bobot(idINTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,hp_idINTEGER NOT NULL,bateraiTEXT NOT NULL,kameraTEXT NOT NULL,ramTEXT NOT NULL,internalTEXT NOT NULL,)
```

i not sure where i got wrong

Comment: Please show us the String that gets generated rather than have people try to figure out what it looks like from your concatenation. Off the top I'd suspect the "NOT NULL"  is redundant for a primary key field, but I'm not an sqlite authority, and until I see the string itself, I'm not committing to that.

Comment: Actually, it is on the error ^_^  `while compiling: CREATE TABLE bobot(idINTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,hp_idINTEGER NOT NULL,bateraiTEXT NOT NULL,kameraTEXT NOT NULL,ramTEXT NOT NULL,internalTEXT NOT NULL,)`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add spaces in your queries

```
CREATE TABLE bobot(idINTEGER
```

so id can't be parsed
Check your query and try again